# How to create a new column with a value from another column in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large excel sheet, and my data looks like this:

```
type        price
shoes        10 
clothes      20
shoes        30
clothes      40
```

I want to move the "30" and "40" value to a new column, and later on I will drop the existing row. I expect it will show up like this:

```
type        price     new price
shoes        10        30
clothes      20        40
```

how can I make it in python?

Thankyou

Comment: what is your code so far?

Comment: ``df.assign(temp=df.groupby("type").cumcount()).pivot("type", "temp", "price").rename_axis(columns=None, index=None).set_axis(["price", "new_price"], axis="columns")``

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df['newprice'] = df.groupby('type')['price'].transform('max')
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset="type", keep="first")
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
      type  price  newprice
0    shoes     10        30
1  clothes     20        40
```

Comment: thankyou for your help! It actually works, but the newprice column results the same value from the price column